# Node.js 6 addon converting Buffer.from() to const UInt8*

Tags: c++, c, node.js, v8, node.js-addon

Hey I know people have asked this question before however for whatever reason the typical SO answer isn't working for me. Basically I have an unsigned byte array:

```
var message = Buffer.from([ 
0x27, 0x52, 0x00, 0x8E
])

myAddon.test(message);
```

In my c++ module I need to get that ByteBuffer into an const UInt8 * data structure.

My code currently is:

```
#include <node.h>
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::Object;
using v8::Value;
using v8::Exception;
void test(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
  Isolate* isolate = args.GetIsolate();

  if (!args[0] ->IsObject()) {
    isolate -> ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        v8::String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "All arguments must be string")
    ));

    return;
  }

  Local<Object> bufferObj = args[0]->ToObject();
  const UInt8* d = (const UInt8*)node::Buffer::Data(bufferObj);
```

This only code that demonstrates the issue. Now whats happening is that Buffer is that I'm getting error: no member named 'Buffer' in namespace 'node'. So when I see examples of people extracting arrays from byte buffers, I get confused. Is there another header file or library I need to import?

Thanks

Comment: "So when I see examples of people extracting arrays from byte buffers,"  Where is an example that works?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you've included `<node_buffer.h>`. Otherwise that is correct.

See also: [Node Buffer to char array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28171481/node-buffer-to-char-array)